# Why some variable of struct take preprocessor to function?

Tags: macros, struct, preprocessor, c-preprocessor

Variables of struct declared by data type of language in the header file. Usually data type using to declare variables, but other data type pass to preprocessors. When we should use to a data type send to preprocessor for declare variables? Why data type and variables send to processor?

```
#define DECLARE_REFERENCE(type, name) \
union { type name; int64_t name##_; }

typedef struct _STRING
 {
   int32_t flags;
   int32_t length;

   DECLARE_REFERENCE(char*, identifier);
   DECLARE_REFERENCE(uint8_t*, string);
   DECLARE_REFERENCE(uint8_t*, mask);
   DECLARE_REFERENCE(MATCH*, matches_list_head);
   DECLARE_REFERENCE(MATCH*, matches_list_tail);

   REGEXP re;

 } STRING;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why *this* code is doing this for declarations? Because as the body of `DECLARE_REFERENCE` shows, when a type and name are passed to this macro it does more than just the declaration - it builds something else out of the name as well, for some other unknown purpose. If you *only* wanted to declare a variable, you wouldn't do this - it does something distinct from simply declaring one variable.

What it actually does? The unions that the macro declares provide a second name for accessing the same space as a different type. In this case you can get at the references themselves, or also at an unconverted integer representation of their bit pattern. Assuming that `int64_t` is the same size as a pointer on the target, anyway.

Using a macro for this potentially serves several purposes I can think of off the bat:

1. Saves keystrokes
2. Makes the code more readable - but *only* to people who already know what the macros mean
3. If the secondary way of getting at reference data is only used for debugging purposes, it can be disabled easily for a release build, generating compiler errors on any surviving debug code
4. It enforces the *secondary* status of the access path, hiding it from people who just want to see what's contained in the struct and its formal interface

Should you do this? No. This does more than just declare variables, it *also* does something else, and that other thing is clearly specific to the gory internals of the rest of the containing program. Without seeing the rest of the program we may never fully understand the rest of what it does.

When you need to do something specific to the internals of *your* program, you'll (hopefully) know when it's time to invent your own thing-like-this (most likely never); but don't copy others.

So the overall lesson here is to identify places where people aren't writing in straightforward C, but are coding to their particular application, and to separate those two, and not take quirks from a specific program as guidelines for the language as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is necessary to have a number of declarations which are guaranteed to have some relationship to each other.  Some simple kinds of relationships such as constants that need to be numbered consecutively can be handled using `enum` declarations, but some applications require more complex relationships that the compiler can't handle directly.  For example, one might wish to have a set of enum values and a set of string literals and ensure that they remain in sync with each other.  If one declares something like:

```
#define GENERATE_STATE_ENUM_LIST \
  ENUM_LIST_ITEM(STATE_DEFAULT, "Default") \
  ENUM_LIST_ITEM(STATE_INIT, "Initializing") \
  ENUM_LIST_ITEM(STATE_READY, "Ready") \
  ENUM_LIST_ITEM(STATE_SLEEPING, "Sleeping") \
  ENUM_LIST_ITEM(STATE_REQ_SYNC, "Starting synchronization") \
  // This line should be left blank except for this comment
```

Then code can use the `GENERATE_STATE_ENUM_LIST` macro both to declare an `enum` type and a string array, and ensure that even if items are added or removed from the list each string will match up with its proper enum value.  By contrast, if the array and enum declarations were separate, adding a new state to one but not the other could cause the values to get "out of sync".

I'm not sure what the purpose the macros in your particular case, but the pattern can sometimes be a reasonable one.  The biggest 'question' is whether it's better to (ab)use the C preprocessor so as to allow such relationships to be expressed in valid-but-ugly C code, or whether it would be better to use some other tool to take a list of states and would generate the appropriate C code from that.